# Rails nested resources and paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

in my routes.rb I have:

```
  resources :boards do
    resources :items
  end
```

now in boards#show I want to show a link to `http://mysite/baord/:board_id/items/new`, running `rake routes` I get:

```
new_board_item GET    /boards/:board_id/items/new(.:format)                        items#new
```

and so I should be able to use `new_board_item_path` but this works only from site.com/board/:board_id/items but i want to use this link in boards#show action but it tells me that:

```
No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"items"}
```

while that's not true!

Comment: Are you passing the board to the board item? E.g. new_board_item_path(@board)

Comment: my fault the error was that... if you convert the comment to an answer i'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the parent resource into the path, so in this case:

```
new_board_item_path(@board)
```

Comment: perfect... just one question: why this isn't necessary in same cases? for example if I want to add a link to items#new in the view for items#index it works without passing the board to the method?